# Best Way to Send an Email 24 Hours After Registration

Tags: php, email, authentication, registration, phpmailer

I am working on a login system that will comply with COPPA regulations by sending an email to a parent's email account a day after registration.

I was wondering about the best way to do this.

I have the sign up time stored in a database column.
I'm using SMTP and PHP Mailer.

Do I need to create a cronjob on the server, or is there a better way
to automate the process of sending a delayed email, preferably using PHP?

Comment: You can use a poor-man's CRON which triggers a "check" with a date/time comparison every Nth time someone loads any one of your pages. Otherwise yes, you need to use a CRON.

Comment: Create a cron job that fires every hour and checks user's who have registered 24 hours before.

Comment: I'm afraid that just sending email won't fulfill the FTC's requirements for getting Verifiable Parental Consent.  http://www.business.ftc.gov/documents/0493-Complying-with-COPPA-Frequently-Asked-Questions

Comment: Thank you for the warning, however, since I'm using this data solely to make users lives better, and I'm not sharing it with third parties, I can in fact use the "email plus" method of verification at this time.  

This is from the article that you linked: "However, if you only use the information internally, and do not disclose it to third parties or make it publicly available, then you may obtain parental consent through use of the Rule’s “email plus” mechanism, as outlined in FAQ H.4 below.  See 16 C.F.R. § 312.5(b)(2)."

I understand that the FTC is revising this system...

Comment: That should work!  As long as you aren't using that data for "any other purpose" you should be fine.  Here's the rule's definition of "Internal Operations" about half way down: http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=59e70080bef64337e0695db7a0a7462e&node=se16.1.312_12&rgn=div8

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this all yourself then a cron job is probably going to be the best bet.

However, if you want to move onto a third party email service, I'd just mailchimp. You can then work with the [Mandril](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php) PHP API which allows you to send messages (I assume emails) with a `send_at` parameter.

Comment: Oh, that's smart. I'm using Mandril. I will look into that. Thanks.